# What is the easiest way to scale a Quicktime MOV to a different size in Windows?

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg, mplayer

I've tried a ffmpeg, and it doesn't know how to read Quicktime MOV, neither does VirtualDub.

Avidemux crashes when I open the Quicktime MOV.

In Linux, I'd just use MEncoder, but I'm telling someone over the phone how to resize this 1080p MOV file, so having them use MEncoder in a command shell would be annoying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) can do this.

Handbrake [seems to be the favourite](https://superuser.com/search?q=handbrake) amongst Super User users, and for good reason. It is open source, supports thousands of codecs, and is both basic AND advanced at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't work with a low screen resolution...

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: If you have a low screen resolution on your computer, like 640x480 on a Netbook, the program doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

Sere this detailed article:
[Step by Step - How to crop, resize and turn MOV videos from your digital camera](http://www.mariomuja.de/2009/04/step-by-step-how-to-crop-resize-and-turn-mov-videos-from-your-digital-camera/).

It uses [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/) together with the [Quicktime plugin for VirtualDub](http://www.tateu.net/software/dl.php?f=qtvd_bin) (read the readme file).

The article is very detailed, including many screenshots, so that reading it may complement your explanations over the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wanna the easiest way, then:
If you have already installed iTunes or Quick Time Alternative, just open the MOV video in Windows Movie Maker and save it with the size you want (but the result will be WMV).

Answer (score 0):

[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/).

> MediaCoder is a free universal media transcoder since 2005. It integrates most popular audio/video codecs and tools in an elegant and transparent manner into an all-in-one transcoding solution. With a flexible and extendable architecture, latest codecs and tools are updated added in constantly. MediaCoder intends to be the swiss army knife for media transcoding in all time.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Super" (I think from ezsoft) program to convert videos to other formats, sizes etc. erightsoft.com/SUPER.html

Well, you must have all needed codecs to perform wanted operations. Download iTunes or Quick Time Alternative (you know...) to have needed MOV codecs (and K-Lite Mega Codec Pack if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualDub with the QuickTime input plugin: http://forums.virtualdub.org/index.php?act=ST&f=7&t=12664